# Installing a Java Plugin on Ubuntu Linux AWS

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, plugins, ubuntu-18.04

I am working with a Python library in AWS Ubuntu linux that requires Java and apparently a Java plugin: [Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/install-jai-imageio-1-0-01.html):

I installed Java 1.11 and the jdk using:

```
 sudo apt install default-jre
 sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless
```

and it appears successful:

```
java -version
```

produces:

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14.1
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04,mixed mode,sharing)
```

and

```
javac -version
```

produces:

```
java 11.0.7
```

I then set in the `.bashrc` the following:

```
#For Java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and ran:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

so if I run:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get:

```
/usr
```

Now I am trying to install the advanced imaging tools package sitting in my root folder: `jai-1_1_2_01-lib-linux-i586-jre.bin` using:

```
$JAVA_HOME 
"bash: /usr: Is a directory"
chmod u+x jai-1_1_2_01-lib-linux-i586-jre.bin
$jai-1_1_2_01-lib-linux-i586-jre.bin
```

Note the '$' appending the first and fourth line and that the second line is output. I am unable to execute the 4th line at all (autocomplete doesn't work and says command not found).

I couldn't figure out a way to set the `$JRE` variable, but I am not sure if this is even the correct way to install the Java plugin so I can use it with Python.

I know this is basic stuff, but I just can't put it all together.

Comment: JAI 1.1.2 is not for Java 11. It was for Java 1.3 or earlier (~May 2000)! [Release notes for 1.1.3](https://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html). It is **ancient**. I don't know if anything modern is capable of running it. I am absolutely certain though that `i586` is **not** a 64-bit build of anything (so that won't work on your 64-bit modern linux platform).

Comment: You are correct. Looks like I was trying to do something fairly out dated and I should probably be using another command line tool. Ill update the question if I find a good PDF scraper.